# Botão para excluir foto PHP com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Boa tarde. Preciso incluir um botão em meu formulário de edição para que eu possa excluir a foto do usuário. Gostaria de fazer com jquey e ajax, estou apredendo ainda. Estou utilizando mysql que armazena apenas o caminho da foto, o arquivo fica em uma pasta no servidor. Alguem poderia dar pelo menos um caminho a seguir... ou alguma idéia
Abaixo tem o meu código:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="foto_aluno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alterar foto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="foto_aluno" name="arquivo">
    </div>

    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btn_excluir">Excluir foto</button>
            </div>
     </div>
```

No final da pagina:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btn_excluir').click(function(){
        alert('Aqui o código para excluir');
     })
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize Ajax em jquery ao clicar no botão para executar o script em php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btn_excluir').click(function(){

$.ajax({method: "POST", url: "linkdoseuscript.php",
            data: { codigodafoto: "xxxxxx" }
       }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Resposta do php: " + msg );
      });


     })
 })
</script>
```

Depois dentro do seu script php vc faz a busca no banco de dados pelo codigo da sua foto, e utilize a função **unlink** do php para remover o arquivo.
(http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php)

Só tome cuidado com essa função para não apagar o que não deve, utilize uma verificação antes se o arquivo realmente existe com **is_file** por exemplo:

```
if (is_file($path.'/'.$file)) { 
     @unlink($path.'/'.$file); 
  }
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria fazer !!! show. Agora deixa eu te perguntar uma coisa, nesse formulário aonde consta esse botão excluir foto, no final dele existe um botão submit, que na hora que clico no botão excluir foto ele acaba executando o submit.. Fui burro não falei isso na pergunta. Estou procurando uma solução.

Comment: Se vc tiver usando `<input type="submit"` é só mudar para `<input type="button"` assim ele vai ter função de um botão comum e não um submit de formulário. O type=submit na tag q é responsável por enviar seu formulário.

Comment: Não esquece depois de setar a resposta como escolhida ta?? assim me ajuda com uns pontinhos kkk

Comment: tipo depois q a pessoa te ajuda aqui no forum e a resposta te ajudou com o problema, é só clicar q nem indicado nessa imagem, pra selecionar a resposta correta. https://i.imgur.com/JnF5V0l.png  Isso ajuda quem está te ajudando, e tbm deixa o forum mais organizado

Comment: Samanta você foi espetacular!!! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Denada, fico feliz em ajudar. bjss